# A TapGestureRecognizer was added into a Label,but it doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a label to receive single tap touch, so I wrote the following code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    UILabel* label;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithframe:CGRectMake(15 30 350 300)];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnLabel:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [label addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
- (void)handleTapOnLabel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    NSLog(@"receive tap.");
}
```

Unluckly,the tapGesture cannot be recognized. Could any one help me with this strange issue? Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be more descriptive with the problem you are having. Is it crashing or is nothing firing?

Comment: [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
Remove this line and try

Comment: @sschale nothing happened when I tap the label.

Comment: @Vignesh it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to add text to the label. `label.text = @"Hello World"`

Comment: I copy pasted your code in a testproject and changed CGRectMake(15 30 350 300) into CGRectMake(15,30,350,300). handleTapOnLabel is fired as expected then...

Comment: I see no problem in your code, in fact tried your code too. Works great. Expect the change i made is in frames as mentioned by @RoelKoops

Comment: well, I know this issue is very strange, because when I create a new project and add into the same code, it works! I can not figour out why , but I think it is not a problem any more. thank you guys above !!!

Comment: @RoelKoops you are right .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A label's user interaction is disabled by default:

`label.userInteractionEnabled = YES`